# Read a textfile for login authentication using a delimiter of ;

Tags: c++, input, text-files

I have a problem of how to read a file using delimiter of ; to read and compare password and username.
Currently my code only allow me to read one username and one password, each in a separated textfile.

I would like my textfile to be in this format and the function will check against the textfile line by line and each user name and password separated with ";'

```
user;pass
user2;pass2
user3;pass3
```

Here's my current code.

```
void Auth()
{
     ifstream Passfile("password.txt", ios::in);
     Passfile>>inpass;
     ifstream Userfile("username.txt", ios::in);
     Userfile>>inuser;
     //system("clear");
     cout<<"USERNAME: ";
     cin>>user;
     cout<<"PASSWORD: ";
     cin>>pass;
     Userfile.close();
     Passfile.close();
     if(user==inuser&&pass==inpass)
     {
     cout<<"\nLogin Success!!\n";
     cin.get();
     Members();
     }
     else
     {
        cout<<"\nLogin Failed!!\n";
         main();
     }
}
```

Comment: `std::string::find` can get you the position of your ;. You could just split it from there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) fo this, just like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool authenticate(const std::string &username, const std::string &password) {
    std::ifstream file("authdata.txt");
    std::string fusername, fpassword;

    while (file) {
        std::getline(file, fusername, ';'); // use ; as delimiter
        std::getline(file, fpassword); // use line end as delimiter
        // remember - delimiter readed from input but not added to output
        if (fusername == username && fpassword == password)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::string username, password;
    std::cin >> username >> password;
    return (int)authenticate(username, password);
}
```

Comment: in my main(), am i able to use if(authenticate(username,password) == true) instead?

Comment: having error when i do that, what u did was in main(), i have a main class which i use it as driver, and in my main i just call that constructor. But i tested your way and still getting an eror too when i change to if(authenticate(username,password) == true) , is there something wrong in what i do?

Answer (score 2):

Several options:

1. `std::getline` takes a terminator, so you can use `';'` as the terminator for your getline after the name rather than the regular `'\n'`
2. Read in a line into a `std::string` (using `getline` or even `>>`) then use `std::string::find` to find the semi-colon and then you can use `std::string::substr()` to separate out the name and password.
3. regex or similar but probably not really what you want here.

The way you have specified the format it appears that it is all stored in one file.

You can either

1. Load the whole file in, and store `std::map< std::string, std::string >` then check the user login.
2. As you are only going to have one login, you read the file after the person has entered their username (and password), a line at a time until you find one that matches the one they have entered.

Comment: glcoder gave an example of how to use with std::getline reading name and password separately, and not storing in a map.